# Texture not moving with Rigged Object

Tags: coordinates

I have a rigged character with armor.  The armor is textured with some noise texture nodes (using cycles).  These look fine in single shots, but as the rigged armor moves the noise texture slides on the object's surface.  This is a problem for an animated video, of course.
The noise texture is set to use the object's coordinates, but I suspect it is using the object's "un-rigged" location rather than the objects location as it moves in response to the rig.  I sure hope that makes sense...
So is there anyway to counter this?  Is that what's going on here?  Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Try using  *Generated* or *UV* coordinates instead (obviously you need to unwrap it to  use UV coordinates).

Cycles procedural textures are 3D, so object coordinates will center the texture around the origin of the object using the material.

This works fine when moving the object and it's origin as a whole, however in cases like yours it will appear to "slide".

Comment: Thank you.  Unfortunately the Generated coordinates create a very different looking texture.  The UV coordinates seem to wipe out the texture all together.  I do have it unwrapped, so....  hmmmm...  What a pain...  Thanks again.

Comment: @user3719 The mapping will change everything, as it's what defines how the texture goes on the surface of the object. That's just how it works. To fix it, try changing the scale.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem. I went into the shading editor and in the "Texture Coordinate" panel, I connected the "Generated" node to the vectors in the next level of panels. Before this, the "Object" node was connected. Once I did this, the texture moved with the animation the way you would expect.